# Cancelling cat potion (night vision)

Tags: the-witcher-3

Earlier in the game I thought upgrading every decent potion was good, but now I have a superior cat night vision potion that last for 12 minutes.

Once I'm out of the dark cave (max 5 min), brightness might as well be darkness, so I have to cancel all potion effects with white honey potion to see normally again. This cancels all other potion effects. It's a bad solution.

Any better ones?

Comment: Can't post a definitive answer, but there is no way to cancel an individual potion as far as I know. I think you could also meditate through it, but that also meditates through your other potions, so that probably doesn't really help you.

Comment: or you could just adventure only at night time :P

Comment: It's a _deliberately_ bad solution.  The game is trying to encourage you to think like a witcher, and do some planning.  If you don't intend to be in the dark for an extended period of time, chasing your cat potion with a bunch of others is bad planning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only 2 ways to cancel potion effects are `White Honey Potion` and `Meditation`. Either way works fine, with the exception that you need to be out of combat to meditate.

Answer (score 1):

There is one alternative in addition to the White Honey Potion and Meditation as @Ben described them in his answer... Whether you consider it a "better" solution to losing all potion effects or not, will be opinionated as it tends to be inconvenient...

That being said, you could raise or lower the brightness of your TV (or in game brightness/gamma settings, I forget what is available).

You might not consider it worthwhile to adjust settings so often, but it is the only way to truly control the cave/outside brightness without managing the cat potion and worrying about other potions that are active as well. It's also possible that simply raising the general brightness will improve your vision enough anyway that you won't have to worry about using the cat potion at all, depending on your TV and eyesight (this is what I did, just gave the brightness a small bump up and it was enough).